# Spring JPa Id empty

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity who own many object

```
@Entity
public class Lodger implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long lodgerId;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "lodger")
  private List<IdentityCard> identityCardList;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "lodger")
 private List<Phone> phoneList;
 ...
```

}

```
@Entity
public class IdentityCard {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long identityCardId;

  private String identyCardValue;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "identity_card_type_id") //without -> identity_card_type_identityCardTypeId
  private IdentityCardType identityCardType;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id")
  private Lodger lodger;
}
```

When i save my lodger, all my object is saved (identiyCard, phone), **but their field  lodger_id is null**.

I was thinking it was supposed to be done automatically when we use cascadeType.all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The owner side of the bi-directioinal associations are in `IdentityCard` and `Phone` entities, this is the same as saying that the `mappedBy` is in `Lodger`'s associations.

So for the persistence of the links you must **set the lodger attribute in** `IdentityCard` and `Phone` entities. Isn't necessary to add this entities to the `Lodger`'s collections but it is fine because you want to save this entities along with `Lodger` using *cascade* option.

Comment: what is the other possibility?

Comment: @roberttrudel that is the way to do it for one-to-many bi-directional association. You could try a "workaround" if you want the owner side in Lodger: use many-to-many instead of one-to-many/many-to-one, set the mappedBy in the Phone and IdentCard and you should add additional controls to keep this entities associated to just one Lodger (eg. unique-check-constraint over Phone's id field of the join-table)